# Búsqueda de datos usando Group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Buen dia, tengo este resultado [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos datos los saco de una tabla que tiene muchos datos repetidos en el numero de carga [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto lo hago con el siguiente query:

```
SELECT TimeStr`,`Reporte_numero_carga_2`,`Reporte_numero_pluma_4`,`Reporte_descripcion_5`,`Reporte_cantidad_piezas_6`,`Reporte_corriente_set_ni_7`,`Reporte_corriente_real_ni_8`,`Tiempo`,`Reporte_corriente_set_cr_11`,`Reporte_corriente_real_cr_12`,`Reporte_torreta_13`,`Reporte_orige0n_carga_14`,`Cargas_por_hora_velocidad`,`Reporte_tiempo_paro_0`,`Reporte_numero_paros_1`
FROM Reportes
WHERE (
    FechaNN BETWEEN "2020-10-08 18:01:00"
    AND "2020-10-09 6:00:00"
  ) AND `Reporte_descripcion_5`NOT IN ("--")
GROUP BY Reporte_numero_carga_2
```

Esto me funciona bien para cuando busco de un dia donde solo hay 60 numeros de carga pero si quiero buscar por semanas el group by solo me mostrara 60 resultados hay una forma de decirle que por cada fecha diferente aplique el group by o puede haber otra manera de buscar estos datos sin usar group by.

Gracias

Comment: Tú puedes agrupar por tantas columnas como desees, sólo tienes que ponerlas separadas por coma luego de `GROUP BY`, algo así: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY Reporte_numero_carga_2, unaColumna, otraColumna, otraColumnaMas, cuantasColumnasQuieras`

Comment: Deberías realizar alguna operación de totales en cada grupo, del tipo `MAX()` , `MIN()`, `SUM()`, `AVG()`, etc. De lo contrario estarás visualizando cualquiera de los registros de cada grupo, no algo representativo del conjunto. Modifica tu pregunta añadiendo el dataset, phpMyAdmin->Exportar, e indica qué resultado esperas para esos datos de ejemplo. Así podremos ayudarte con la consulta